# Attack of the Middle Square Weyl Sequence PRNG

Tags: cryptanalysis, pseudo-random-generator

The Middle Square Weyl Sequence PRNG was proposed as illustration of properties of CSPRNGs in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62743/555) (now deleted). This PRNG was introduced by Bernard Widynski in [*Middle Square Weyl Sequence RNG*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00358) ([arXiv, 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00358)). That was without claim of cryptographic security, but v5 of the paper conjectures that it would "be difficult to determine the internal state by examining the outputs".

The PRNG has a 128-bit state consisting of two 64-bit variables $x$ and $w$. The PRNG input consists of the initial $x_0$ and $w_0$, and an odd value $s$. The state's evolution and 32-bit pseudorandom outputs $r_i$ are defined (for $i\ge0$) by
$$\begin{align}
r_i&\gets x_i\bmod2^{32}\\
w_{i+1}&\gets(w_i+s)\bmod 2^{64}\\
x_{i+1}&\gets((x_i^2+w_{i+1})\bmod 2^{64})\ggg32
\end{align}$$
where $\ggg32$ swaps the halves of its 64-bit left argument.

<sup>[The notation was modified so that $r_0$ is output, for consistency with [an answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62755/555)]</sup>

The paper gives a reference C99 implementation (with input $x_0=w_0=0$ and a certain $s$; the output starts at $r_1$)

```
uint64_t x = 0, w = 0, s = 0xb5ad4eceda1ce2a9;
inline static uint32_t msws() {
   x *= x; x += (w += s); return x = (x>>32) | (x<<32);
}
```

Assume we have a $r_i$ for $0\le i\le9$. How can the rest of the sequence be predicted efficiently? That would be a total break.

If not feasible, lesser breaks (only distinguishing the output from random, or requiring more plaintext, or working only for a fraction of the inputs) are also welcome.

Comment: It has no NP hard form, XOR to diffuse /confuse and it's just too simple. You typically trade algorithmic entropy against NP rigidity as in ISAAC v BBS.  My waters say that it can't possibly be secure.

Comment: If there are no sources of randomness used in the algorithm, distinguishing its outputs from random seems trivial: Simply check to see if the first $n$ outputs are the outputs from running the algorithm. Similarly, if you know the first $n$ outputs and want to predict the output for $n + 1$, just run the algorithm for $n + 1$ iterations and output the result. Or maybe I am misunderstanding the nature of the security game?

Comment: @EllaRose: I had assumed that the attacker is not given the initial values of $x$ and $w$.  If the attacker is also not given the value $s$, then my attack would still work (it just that it needs 6 outputs to recover the state)

Comment: @EllaRose The point is the $x$ and $w$ are unknown in a real implementation. It looks like $s$ can vary too as long as it remains odd.

Comment: The 5th version of that paper is now claiming it's cryptographically secure...interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets look at the computations that the function does to the internal state.

We'll denote the state of the variables when we start the attack as $x_0 = (a, b)$ and $w_0 = (c, d)$, where I will use the notation $(i, j)$ to mean the 64 bit number which has $i$ as the upper 32 bits, and $j$ as the lower 32 bits (and so $a, b, c, d$ are 32 bits each).  Note that $x_0, w_0$ need not be the initial state of the PRNG, instead it's the state when the initial output was generated.

Then, the previous step exposes $b$ (and so that is known to the attacker).

Then, it squares $x_0$ modulo $2^{64}$, replacing $x_0 = (a, b)$ with $x_0^2 = (2 a b + (b^2 >> 32), b^2\  \bmod 2^{32})$.  As the attacker knows $b$, the attacker can replace this with the linear operation $x_0^2 = (h_0 a + h_2, h_1)$, where $h_0, h_1, h_2$ are known (to the attacker) constants (as it gives the same mapping from previous state to new state).

Then, the algorithm adds $w$ to $x$, that can be modeled as:

$x_0^2 + w_0 = (h_0 a + h_2 + c + \epsilon_0, h_1 + d)$, where $\epsilon_0$ is either 0 or 1, depending on whether a carry from the lower 32 bits happened.

Then, it adds the constant $s$ to $w$, this can be modeled as $w + s = (c + s_{hi} + \epsilon_1, d + s_{lo})$, where $\epsilon_1$ is either 0 or 1, depending on whether a carry from the lower 32 bits happened (and $s = (s_{hi}, s_{lo})$

Then, it rotates $x$, giving $x_1 = (h_1 + d, h_0a + h_2 + c + \epsilon_0)$, and outputs the lower 32 bits $h_0a + h_2 + c + \epsilon_0$.

The new state is $x_1 = (h_1 + d, h_0a + h_2 + c + \epsilon_0)$ and $w_1 = (c + s_{hi} + \epsilon_1, d + s_{lo})$; that is, it is one of 4 linear functions of the previous state (depending on the values of $\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1$)

Continuing on for three more iterations, the resulting states will remain one of a small number of known linear functions of the initial state; the output will also be a linear function of the state.  With four outputs, the attacker can iterate through the possible $\epsilon$ values, and solve for the initial states.  If you go through the equations, you'll find that you can recover $c, d$ from the third and fourth outputs; using the value $c$ gives you the value of $a$ from the second output (and you're given $b$ as the first output).

Comment: @fgrieu: actually, I'm using $x_0$ not to signify the initial state, but instead the state of the system when the first output we were given was produced (which will likely mean that $x, w$ had gone through at least one iteration)

Comment: So, $h_0$ = $b^2 mod 2^{32}$ but how do I get $h_1$,$h_2$,$c$, $d$?

Comment: @S.L.: actually, $h_1 = b^2 \bmod 2^{32}$, $h_0 = 2b$ and $h_2 = (b^2 >> 32)$

Comment: I'm trying to implement. I see that $h0a+h2+c+ϵ0$ actually gives a 64 bit number, how does that work if it represents 32 bits?

Comment: $r0,x0,w0 = 2397353388,11805728105293985196,2847934365896495385$
$r1, x1, w1 = 1956483837, 4921554038045905661, 15939140708061950914$

I can't seem to reconcile